# What's the difference between 'rpcallowip' and 'rpcbind'?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, bitcoin.conf

What's the difference between these two settings in the bitcoin conf file?
'rpcallowip' and 'rpcbind'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could be running Bitcoin Core on your desktop and issuing RPC commands from your laptop. In this example you might want to put `rpcbind=0.0.0.0` and `rpcallowip=192.168.1.10` or your laptop’s lan IP.

Rpcbind binds to a socket, this happens in the networking layer. Without it packets won’t even reach bitcoin core. Rpcallowip is used for authorization which happens in the application layer. Packets need to be able to reach bitcoin core before the command can be authorized so in a sense rpcallowip needs to be a subnet of rpcbind